# msbuild task in NAnt does not compile WiX project in Prebuild

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, wix, nant, nantcontrib

This WiX Setup project compiles in Visual Studio without a problem.

However, running it in NAnt using the msbuild task shows the following error.

Heat Prebuild event:

```
"$(SolutionDir)\App_Tools\WiX Toolset v3.8\bin\heat.exe" dir "$(SolutionDir)\App_Shell \bin\$(ConfigurationName)" -dr "AppDirectory" -cg "AppComponentGroup" -t   "$(ProjectDir)Filter.xslt" -gg -g1 -sf -srd -sreg -var "var.AppAppPath" -out   "$(ProjectDir)\App_HarvestedHeatFile.wxs"
```

msbuild task:

```
<msbuild project="App_Installers\App.Setup\App.Setup.wixproj">
        <property name="Configuration" value="Release"/>
        <property name="target" value="Rebuild"/>
        <property name="verbosity" value="Normal"/>
</msbuild>
```

Error message Prebuild:

```
  [msbuild] Build started 03.02.2014 15:38:35.
  [msbuild] Project "E:\Projects\Company\App\Development\trunk\src\App_Inst
allers\App.Setup\App.Setup.wixproj" on node 1 (default targets).
  [msbuild] AssignCultures:
  [msbuild]   Culture: en-US
  [msbuild]   Culture: de-DE
  [msbuild] PreBuildEvent:
  [msbuild]   "*Undefined if not building a solution or within Visual Studio*\App_Tools\WiX Toolset v3.8\bin\heat.exe" dir "*Undefined if not building a soluti
on or within Visual Studio*\App_Shell\bin\Release" -dr "AppDirectory" -cg "AppComponentGroup" -t "E:\Projects\Company\App\Development\trunk\src\App_Inst
allers\App.Setup\Filter.xslt" -gg -g1 -sf -srd -sreg -var "var.AppAppPath" -ou
t "E:\Projects\Company\App\Development\trunk\src\App_Installers\App.Setup\
\App_HarvestedHeatFile.wxs"
  [msbuild]   The system cannot find the path specified.
  [msbuild] C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\wix2010.targets(81
6,5): error MSB3073: The command ""*Undefined if not building a solution or with
in Visual Studio*\App_Tools\WiX Toolset v3.8\bin\heat.exe" dir "*Undefined if n
ot building a solution or within Visual Studio*\App_Shell\bin\Release" -dr "AppDirectory" -cg "AppComponentGroup" -t "E:\Projects\Company\App\Development
\trunk\src\App_Installers\App.Setup\Filter.xslt" -gg -g1 -sf -srd -sreg -var "
var.AppAppPath" -out "E:\Projects\Company\App\Development\trunk\src\App_In
stallers\App.Setup\\App_HarvestedHeatFile.wxs"" exited with code 3. [E:\Projec
ts\Company\App\Development\trunk\src\App_Installers\App.Setup\App.Setup.w
ixproj]
  [msbuild] Done Building Project "E:\Projects\Company\App\Development\trunk
\src\App_Installers\App.Setup\App.Setup.wixproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

  [msbuild]
  [msbuild] Build FAILED.
  [msbuild]
  [msbuild] "E:\Projects\Company\App\Development\trunk\src\App_Installers\R
oCo.Setup\App.Setup.wixproj" (default target) (1) ->
  [msbuild] (PreBuildEvent target) ->
  [msbuild]   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\wix2010.targets(
816,5): error MSB3073: The command ""*Undefined if not building a solution or wi
thin Visual Studio*\App_Tools\WiX Toolset v3.8\bin\heat.exe" dir "*Undefined if
 not building a solution or within Visual Studio*\App_Shell\bin\Release" -dr "R
oCoDirectory" -cg "AppComponentGroup" -t "E:\Projects\Company\App\Developme
nt\trunk\src\App_Installers\App.Setup\Filter.xslt" -gg -g1 -sf -srd -sreg -var
 "var.AppAppPath" -out "E:\Projects\Company\App\Development\trunk\src\App_
Installers\App.Setup\\App_HarvestedHeatFile.wxs"" exited with code 3. [E:\Proj
ects\Company\App\Development\trunk\src\App_Installers\App.Setup\App.Setup
.wixproj]
  [msbuild]
  [msbuild]     0 Warning(s)
  [msbuild]     1 Error(s)
  [msbuild]
  [msbuild] Time Elapsed 00:00:00.10

BUILD FAILED
```

Comment: what preprocessor variable are you using within the pre-build event?

Comment: "AppAppPath" is the preprocessor variable. I have added the prebuild event to the issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your case, the issue is with the $(SolutionDir) property and not your pre-processor. The issue is that the property $(SolutionDir) is not getting defined and thats why the error. MSBuild does not define the SolutionDir property so you'll need to manually specify it:

```
msbuild.exe /p:SolutionDir=
```

Did the pre-processor variable (AppAppPath) get evaluated properly using VS? I was thinking that you need to do something like this to get the right value:
http://www.ageektrapped.com/blog/setting-properties-for-wix-in-msbuild/

Comment: I added SolutionDir to the msbuild task and the Prebuild event is successful. Now the SignOutput fails with MSB3073 errors. See error in question update

Comment: Please mark this an the answer to your original question and create a new question. You cannot keep editing the same question, think about other people who are going to use this forum, this should be useful for everyone.

Comment: anyways couldnt resist posting this path issue that I saw "E:\Projects\Company\R
oCo\Development\trunk\src\App_Shell\App.csproj" is there a folder named "Roco", it doesnt look like thats the path you want it to look for based on the other files and paths that you have posted. Anyways check that.

Comment: It should be "App". Thanks for noticing that :)